# why beforedestory is not called while refresh, but created gets called?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to refresh page in vue.js.

doing that causes `created` hook to get called. Why not `destroyed` hook? if `created` hook is called, it means that it should have been destroyed. Why doesn't it get called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`destroyed` lifecycle hook isn't triggered because Vue instance isn't unmounted on window refresh or close.

In case it needs to be triggered, the instance should be destroyed explicitly:

```
const vue = new Vue(...).$mount("#app");

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
  vue.$destroy();
});
```

Due to certain limitations of `beforeunload` and `unload` events, `beforeDestroy` and `destroyed` hooks are limited to synchronous code when they are triggered this way, asynchronous operations won't be completed.

Comment: Can you tell me why it's not unmounted? if created hook gets called, it means mounted hook gets called too. So mounting happens all over again. why not unmounting happens ?

Comment: The app isn't mounted by magic when the page opens. It's mounted because `$mount` is explicitly called, therefore, `created` hook is called. Similarly, it's not unmounted when the page closes but when `$destroy` is explicitly called. Vue could make `$destroy` called automatically like the answer suggests but preferred to leave it to users for some reason, most likely because this causes more problems than solves, notably with async `destroyed`.